# store html data for dynamic ajax loading

Tags: html, ajax, dynamic, server, loading

I have a site on which Im trying to dynamically update the index.html page, replacing content held in a div, with new html content gathered from an AJAX request to a server holding my other html data. My question is how should I store my html on the server side. Should i create new html files with the content in the body, and try to extract the html from the body? Or Should I try to somehow store just the (div with a few elements inside) fragment I want to use?

Comment: You're asking which one you should use, which leads me to believe this question is opinionated. Please update your question with your code and we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store the div and its contents in an external file, load it with ajax, and put the loaded content inside your main html file. Give a look into [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) exemple to see how to do it.